# Powershell - Wait input for 10 seconds

Tags: powershell

```
$inputYN = Read-Host "(defaults to y in 10 sec) [y/n] ";
```

If user doesn't provide any input in 10 second then default `$inputYN` should go to "Yes" and move forward to next task.

Comment: Part of the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150161/waiting-for-user-input-with-a-timeout

Comment: I am new to powershell and try to do this.
If you have any code for this task, please post it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Your question intrigued me. I'm not sure how well this will work, but I tested it a couple of times and got the correct keys back. Doesn't work too well if you try to enter capital letters. There has to be a better way than this, though. You can always check with other forums like [PowerShell.com](http://powershell.com/cs/forums/) or [PowerShell.org](http://powershell.org/wp/forums/) to get a different crowd.

```
function Get-Answer {
    $counter = 0
    while($counter++ -lt 100){
        if($Host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable){
            #You could check to see if it was the "Shift Key or another"
            $key = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyUp")
            break
        }
        else{
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
            $key = $false
        }
    }
    return ($key)
}

Write-Host 'Enter y/n'
$answers = Get-Answer
if($answers -eq $false -or ($answers.Character -eq 'y')){
    "Yes is default"
}
elseif($answers.Character -eq 'n'){
    "NO!!!!"
}
else{
    "Invalid Key $($answers.Character): `"YES`" is being used now."
}
```