# Powershell- Wait for x seconds on read host

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

How to wait for x seconds on read host in Powershell? what I'm trying to achieve xis to prompt for user input for x seconds, if the user doesn't enter the value i needed. i use the default Value.

Currently when i use read-host its waiting on user input indefinitely, i want to have a timeout on it. how can i achieve this. the code i have is below. im unable to find any option that lets me define a timer on this.

```
$input = Read-Host ("Enter Y or N") 
if(!input)
{
   $input = Y
}
```

This is regarding possible duplicate question:
In that post all answers were directed more towards whether user pressed a key or not. they did not mention how to capture the user input in there to use it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Waiting for user input with a timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150161/waiting-for-user-input-with-a-timeout)

Comment: in that post all answers were directed more towards whether user pressed a key or not. they did not mention how to capture the user input in there to use it?

Comment: Okay, check this [Powershell - Wait input for 10 seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964542/powershell-wait-input-for-10-seconds) there is an answer that might suit you better, as it retrieves the value.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. should i go ahead and delete this question?