# Script not getting multiline input

Tags: powershell

I have the following script that allows me to get user IDs on the console and then check expiration dates of relevant users' AD accounts. The part gathering the IDs is as below:

```
[array]$input = (Read-Host “Staff Numbers: ”).Split([System.Environment]::NewLine, [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

However when I paste the staff numbers of the user to the console, it reads only the 1st line and ends the script. The other numbers after the first are just displayed on the console after.

Any idea on what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Read-Host` is supposed to take only one line, as per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host?view=powershell-6):

> The Read-Host cmdlet reads **a line of input** from the console.

If you want to get multiple lines you can either:

- import data from file
- use `Read-Host` inside a loop [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45578145/9902555)

  ```bsh
  $arr = @(While($line=(Read-Host).Trim()){$line})
  ```
- separate values by any other character (comma, semicolon etc.) as suggested [on /r/PowerShell](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/4em3qe/is_it_possible_to_do_a_multiline_readhost_into_an/d219sfg/)

  ```bsh
  $userInput = read-host "Enter a list of comma separated hostnames"
  $data = $userInput.split(",").trim(" ")
  ```