# Add multiline body to powershell email

Tags: powershell

I´m trying to add multilines to the body, but can´t find the fix. I tried to do it with html but i don´t know how...

```
$Email       = "x"
$Internal    = "x"
$Subject     = "New"
$Body        = "Sending new files. Cheers!"

[array]$attachments = Get-ChildItem "\\ip\ftp$\new\Fac" *.pdf

if ([array]$attachments -eq $null) {
}

else {

$Msg = @{
    to          = $Email
    cc          = $Internal
    from        = "to"
    Body        = $Body
    subject     = "$Subject"
    smtpserver  = "server"
    BodyAsHtml  = $True
    Attachments = $attachments.fullname
}

Send-MailMessage @Msg

}
```

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650961/use-read-host-to-enter-multiple-lines/62380806#62380806) helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a multi-line string literal, use [here-strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules#here-strings):

```
$Body = @'
Multiple
lines

go

here
'@
```

You can also construct a multi-line string from multiple individual strings with the `-join` operator:

```
$Body = 'Line1','Line2','Line3' -join [Environment]::NewLine
```

But since you want HTML, better join with `<br />` instead:

```
$Body = 'Line1','Line2','Line3' -join '<br />'
```