# How to prevent Powershell 5.1 from accepting linebreaks within Read-Host input as an 'Enter.'

Tags: powershell

I have been scripting a sysadmin solution for checking user accounts. Currently our department's process is to check individual users based on their presentation on a newhire report, sent out as an excel attachment. The solution I was able to script in ISE involves the following script to allow for a get-host command to permit a copy & paste of a column of user information, which is then enumerated into an array for later processing in the script. Below is the function that is working to this end within the ISE.

```
function Read-Input
{
    #Get the input from the host.    
    $column= Read-Host("`nPlease paste the column of [redacted] from the daily reports spreadsheet, and press enter.`n") 
    #Replace all linebreaks with commas
    $noLineBreaks=$column.Replace("`n",",") 
    #Use commas to separate the large string into individual items in an array
    $array=$noLineBreaks.split(",") 
    #Send the array back for processing.
    Return $array
}
```

However when attempting to use the above script to get the input from a user by a simple copy/paste within a Powershell console, I am greeted with a warning that states:

> 'Warning, you are about to paste text that contains multiple lines. If
> you paste this text into your shell, it may result in the unexpected
> execution of commands. Do you wish to continue?'

Sure enough, it takes the first linebreak from the copied excel column as the 'enter' keypress, causing it to only take the first input instead of allowing the subsequent foreach loops to iterate through information for various functions.

I would prefer it if the intended users of this script wouldn't need to have ISE opened for the purposes of simplicity. Is there ANY way that I can get around this in a normal Powershell terminal?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you want `$column = Get-ClipBoard`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650961/use-read-host-to-enter-multiple-lines

Comment: That could be a possibility! I was hoping for it to be a more straightforward user experience to assist people who are not familiar and need to fill temporarily during vacations or sick days. I'll look into if that can be implemented, maybe by getting the script to prompt the users to copy the column, then hit any key to continue...

Comment: You could show the (partial) contents of the clipboard to the user and prompt them for "yes/no" - then keep polling with `Get-Clipboard` until user accepts the "pasted" input

Comment: Note that ISE is no longer being developed. https://code.visualstudio.com/download

Comment: Yeah I'm aware. It has been a while since I've had to do scripting for prod, and I've been dragging my feet.

I might as well transition away. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Are you trying to have the users copy info from an Excel-cell into the PowerShell console? Why can't you automate reading the Excel documents without user intervention on each step?

Comment: That was shot down, as the agreed process requires manual accounting of the report and the contents to catch a large variety of issues. Given that, making it 100% automated would be outside of the intended use of the script, which is to just make the repetitive and tedious common actions quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below link provided by BaconBurner is the exact solution I needed.

[Use Read-Host to enter multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650961/use-read-host-to-enter-multiple-lines)

Here is what my script has been changed to.

```
function Read-Input
{
    #Get the input from the host.    
    $column = while (1) {
        Read-Host | set r
        if (!$r) {break}
        $r
    }

    #Replace all linebreaks with commas
    $noLineBreaks=$column.Replace("`n",",") 

    #Use commas to separate the large string into individual items in an array
    $array=$noLineBreaks.split(",") 

    #Send the array back for processing.
    Return $array
}
```

There appears to be a way to clean this up a bit in that topic, I will see about updating answer later as time permits to make it more readable and broadly useful to anyone else who comes across this question.

Comment: `while($r=Read-Host){$r}` will do too :)