# PowerShell: Wait for a time to get user input

Tags: powershell, user-input

I want to make a PowerShell script that will wit for 4 seconds to get any user input .If user gives no input then it will skip it.

I only know the "Read-Host" command .I am using this code right now.

```
Read-Host "Press enter to continue..."
```

Please, help. Thanks!!!

Comment: this may be relevant to your situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150161/waiting-for-user-input-with-a-timeout

Comment: I saw the answer but couldn't understand it......